# crear tabla en ajax, el numero de tr depende de la cantidad de posiciones de un array

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

hola nunca he preguntado por aqui, pero espero que puedan ayudarme, ok les explicare lo que quiero, estoy intentando crear una tabla en ajax para guardar los resultados que tengo en un array, por lo que el numero de tr de dicha tabla debe ser igual que las posiciones de mi array, el problema es que cuando lo corro me sale este error: Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded, lo cual no entiendo. aqui esta mi codigo de ajax:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/Manager/metricsAdvocates',
    type:  'post',
    data:  {'sup':sup, 'dateM':dateM},
    dataType: 'json',

     success: function(response){

       array=response;

       var tabla = '<table class="table table-hover table-bordered table-striped" id="tableManag">';
         tabla += '<thead>';
         tabla += '<tr>';
         tabla += '<th>vhur</th><th>Advocate</th><th>Attendance</th>';
         tabla += '</tr>';
         tabla += '</thead>';
         tabla += '<tbody>';
         tr = '';

        for (i=0; i < array.length; i++){
              alert('succest');

             tr += '<tr>';
             tr += '<td id = "vhur"></td><td id="Advocate"></td><td id= "att"></td>';
             tr += '</tr>';
          }

         tabla += tr;
         tabla += '</tbody></table>';

         $('#tableAtt').html( tabla );

       }
     });
```

aparte tengo el metodo donde le doy los valores a mi arreglo pero el error me sale desde el ajax es mas nisiquiera me redirecciona al otro metodo.

Gracias espero que puedan ayudarme.

Comment: ¿Podrías decir lo que se muestra si pones esto después del `success`?:  `console.log(response);`.  Y **quita esto dentro del for: `alert('succest');`**. Si hay miles/millones de registros, vas a lanzar miles/millones de `alert`... oh, noooo.

Comment: Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at Ab (jquery.min.js:4)
    at Ab (jquery.min.js:4)
    at Ab (jquery.min.js:4)
    at Ab (jquery.min.js:4)
    at Ab (jquery.min.js:4)
    at Ab (jquery.min.js:4)
    at Ab (jquery.min.js:4)
    at Ab (jquery.min.js:4)
    at Ab (jquery.min.js:4)
    at Ab (jquery.min.js:4)
    at Ab (jquery.min.js:4)
    at Ab (jquery.min.js:4)
    at Ab (jquery.min.js:4)

Comment: ¿Quitaste el `alert` que había dentro del for? ¿La llamada que estás haciendo está supuesta a devolver muchísimos datos?

Comment: También tienes que modificar lo que pasas en `data`, los valores de la izquierda no pueden ir entre comillas, debe estar así: **`data:  {sup: sup, dateM: dateM},`**

Comment: si ya quite el alert tenias razon saldrian muchos alert, pero,  segun mi consulta a la base de datos,  devuelve un arreglo de tres columnas y 13 filas,  ese arreglo es el que almacena en el response ? en el metodo yo lo mando con esta linea.       echo json_encode($arrayAdvocates);

Comment: en otros ajax lo que paso en el data lo pongo entre comillas y no me pone ningun problemas, voy a cambiarlo a ver si da.